# CakePHP project Issue(FCKEditor and Broken links)

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working on a project which is auction  site and it is actually
clone of www.swoop.com.
This clone is developed on CakePHP platform and I have a issues there.
I purchase that script from http://www.moneymakersnetwork.info/products/Swoopo-Clone-PHP-Script.html and there is a demo: http://demo.bidscout.net (username: demo, password: password1).

In that cms there is FCKEditor integrated and it is not working. It is
gives me that following error message:

> The requested URL /js/fckeditor/editor/fckeditor.html was not found on
>   this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

And if I add new category it is come to a drop down list box and those
links are broken.

Ok, my host is like this: http://demosite.org/mysite/.

App and webroot folders are located in http://demosite.org/mysite/app and http://demosite.org/mysite/app/webroot.

I have a cofig.php file and it is look like this (http://demosite.org/mysite/app/config):

```
<?php
   $config = array(

       'Database' => array(
           'driver'     => 'mysql',
           'persistent' => false,
           'host'       => 'localhost',
           'login'      => 'myuser',    
           'password'   => 'mypassword',    
           'database'   => 'mydb',    
           'prefix'     => ''    
       ),    

       'App' => array(
           'encoding'               => 'UTF-8',    
           'baseUrl'                => '',    
           'base'                   => '',    
           'dir'                    => 'app',    
           'webroot'                => 'webroot',
           'name'                   => 'mysite',
           'url'                    => 'http://demo.org/mysite/',
           'timezone'               => 'Asia/Jakarta',
           'language'               => 'en',
           'email'                  => 'test@demo.com',
           'theme'                  => 'ddbids',
           'currency'               => 'USD',
           'pageLimit'              => 100,
           'bidHistoryLimit'        => 10,    
           'remember_me'            => '+30 days',
           'auctionUpdateFrequency' => 1,
           'timeSyncFrequency'      => 9,    
           'gateway'                => true,
           'demoMode'               => false,
           'noAutobids'             => false,
           'cronTime'               => 1,

           'Image' => array(
               'thumb_width'  => 100,
               'thumb_height' => 100,
               'max_width'    => 340,
               'max_height'   => 230
           ),

           'Dob' => array(
               'year_min' => date('Y') - 100,
               'year_max' => date('Y') - 17
           )
       ),

       'Paypal' => array(
           'url'   => 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',    
           'email' => '',    
           'lc'    => 'GB'
       ),

       'Email' => array(    
           'delivery' => 'smtp',
           'sendAs'   => 'both',
           'host'     => 'localhost',
           'port'     => 25,
           'timeout'  => 60,
           'username' => '',
           'password' => ''
       ),

       'Cache' => array(    
           //'disable' => true,
           'check' => false,
           'time' => '' // relative time such as +1 day, +2 months, +3 minutes
       ),

       'debug' => 1

   );
?>
```

I am very new to the CakePHP. Please help me.

Comment: where u put your FCK files???

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that (probably) the links are hard coded and expect your site to be at:

http://demosite.org/ instead of http://demosite.org/mysite/

this way your /js/fckeditor/editor/fckeditor.html can be found.

At least that's how it sounds to me this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.
put the whole FCK folder in js FOLDER of in APP ie., `APP/webroot/js/Editor`